# Custom Layout Interact with another layouts TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a custom Layout shown below and I would like to update the TextViews text from within that layout file. But the TextView is not within the layout file at all.

Sorry I don't know how to properly describe what I am implementing. If anyone could even advise on the correct terminology that would be much appreciated.

Basically I want to change the TextView from AM to PM when the button that is inflated from com.grogorian.android.control.MinutePicker is clicked. I am using the below java within com.grogorian.android.control.MinutePicker,but keep getting a null pointer

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/L"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">  
<com.grogorian.android.control.MinutePicker
        android:id="@+id/Picker2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.grogorian.android.control.MinutePicker>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/AMPMIdentifier" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AM" />
```

Here is the Java

```
    LinearLayout L = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.L);
    TextView Identifier = (TextView)L.findViewById(R.id.AMPMIdentifier);
    Identifier.setText("PM");
```

EDIT: Here is the code from

```
    but = new Button( context );
    but.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
    but.setText( "-" );

    // Decrement once for a click
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
LinearLayout L = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.L);
    TextView Identifier = (TextView)L.findViewById(R.id.AMPMIdentifier);
    Identifier.setText("PM");
        }
    });
            this.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
    LayoutParams elementParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ELEMENT_WIDTH, ELEMENT_HEIGHT );

        addView( but, elementParams );
```

Comment: Not enough info.  Show the class where you set your layout as well as the com.grogorian.android.control.MinutePicker... that'll give someone a fighting chance to help you.

Comment: Added the requested code. Thank you

Comment: I don't see a `setContentView` in there anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to guess, right now you're trying to find, in the `OnCLickListener` listener, the `LinearLayout` **L** from the layout file you posted(which you probably use as the layout for an `Activity`?!). This will fail because the `LinearLayout` will not be found and the object will be `null`. If this what you are doing then try another approach:

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent(); // I assumed your MinutePicker extends LinearLayout
      LinearLayout L = (LinearLayout) parent.getParent();
      TextView Identifier = (TextView)L.findViewById(R.id.AMPMIdentifier);
      Identifier.setText("PM");
    }
});
```

I haven't tested the code above(well, I don't even know how exactly your `MinutePicker` is built). If this isn't the problem you may want to add the full exception stacktrace you may get.